# Form not being checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want there to be server side checks within my code. Once the form is submitted, I should have the form checked server side and the error should be echoed back. But as it is now, no matter what I do, an account is always registered. The submit button skips all server side checks and just adds the account into the database.

Here is my Javascript

```
 $("#registerSubmit").click(function(e) {
            document.getElementById("registerSubmit").disabled = true; 
            document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = "Creating account, please wait...<br>";
            $("#strongText").fadeIn();
            e.preventDefault();
            $("input[name='username']").val($("#input-2").val());
            $("input[name='firstname']").val($("#input-1").val());
            $("input[name='password1']").val($("#input-3").val());
            $("input[name='password2']").val($("#input-4").val());
            $("input[name='email']").val($("#input-5").val());
            var username = $("input[name='username']").val();
            var firstname = $("input[name='firstname']").val();
            var password1 = $("input[name='password1']").val();
            var password2 = $("input[name='password2']").val();
            var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    firstname: firstname,
                    password1: password1,
                    password2: password2,
                    email: email
                },
                url: 'checkuser.php',
                success: function(data) { //Receives the data from the php code 
                    //console.log(data);
                    if (data == "Unavailable") {
                        document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = "Username Unavailable<br>";
                        document.getElementById("registerSubmit").disabled = false; 
                    } else if(data == 'Email_Exists') {
                        document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = "Email Already Registered<br>";
                        document.getElementById("registerSubmit").disabled = false; 
                    } else {
                        $.post(
                            'registerCheck.php', 
                            $('#registerform').serialize(),
                            function(data,status){
                                document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = data + "<br>";
                                window.location.href = "/login.php";
                            }
                        );
                        //window.location.href = "/login.php";
                    }

                },
                error: function(xhr, err) {
                    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?php
require 'databaseinformation.php';

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];
$password2 = $_POST["password2"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$username = $_POST["username"];

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed.";
    exit();
}

if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 15) {
    echo "Username must be between 3 and 15 characters";
} elseif (strlen($password1) < 5 || strlen($password1) > 25) {
    echo "Password must be between 5 and 25 characters";
} elseif ( $password1 !== $password2) {
    echo "Password are mismatched";
} elseif (strpos($email,'@') !== true || strpos($email,'.') !== true) {
    echo "Not a valid E-Mail";
} elseif ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE username = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        //echo json_encode("0");
        echo "Unavailable";

        //if unavailable
        // header('Location: /register.html'); 
    }
    else {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `accounts` WHERE email = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        //echo json_encode("2");
        echo "Email_Exists";
        //if unavailable
        // header('Location: /register.html'); 
    }
    else {
        //echo json_encode("1");
        echo "1";
    }

}
    }

}
$mysqli->close(); 

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? It sounds like the `preventDefault()` is not being called.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no errors in console or anywhere as far as I'm aware. I do believe `preventDefault()` IS being called because the other textboxes are being populated.

Comment: What is the returned value of `data` from the first AJAX request?

Comment: I believe it returns a "1" or anything other than "Unavailable" or "Email Exists" because all I am able to see echo "Account successfuly created" which is the `data` that is returned from `registerCheck.php` which is the second AJAX request

Comment: You cannot cancel form's `submit` event from `click` event listener. `preventDefault` in your code cancel `click` event, not form's `submit` event. So you have to listen form's `submit` event instead of `click` event. And all your code should be in `submit` event listener.

Comment: @hindmost I'm a little confused on what you're saying. So you're saying that I should change `$("#registerSubmit").click(function(e)` to `$("#registerSubmit").submit(function(e)`? I changed it and now I just keep getting all the errors that the php echos and the form never submits.

Comment: @pshyoulost No, this way:`$("#your_form_id").submit(...)`

Comment: @hindmost Does the same thing as my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in you email validation code , No matter what you do you always ends on getting `Not a valid E-Mail` message from the server. And, Since it is not handled on AJAX success , **else block** is always executed and hence your next *POST block*.

So, Instead this for email validation ,

```
} elseif (strpos($email, '@') == false || strpos($email, '.') == false) {
```

or

```
} elseif (strpos($email, '@') == 0 || strpos($email, '.') == 0) {
```

---

#### Why was it not working?

```
!==     Not identical
```

eg. $x !== $y   Returns true if $x is not equal to $y, or they are not of the same type

And , `strpos($email, '@')` returns type Integer which you have pitted against boolean.

---

And , you have left out different validation message like ,

- Username must be between 3 and 15 characters
- Password must be between 5 and 25 characters
- Password are mismatched

Please handle the all in AJAX success.

```
if(data == "Unavailable") {                
}else if(data == 'Email_Exists') {          
}else if (data == 'Username must be between 3 and 15 characters'){
}else if (data == 'Password must be between 5 and 25 characters'){
}else if (data == 'Password are mismatched'){
}else if(data=='Not a valid E-Mail'){
}
```